# Function works OK, but returns garbage

Tags: c, function, floating-point, return-value

I have this function:

```
float calc_nnc(struct ImageWindow *window1, struct ImageWindow *window2) {
    /* More code */
    double numerator = (double) sum_a_x_b;
    double divisor = ( sqrt(sum_a) * sqrt(sum_b) );
    double result = numerator / divisor;
    float resultf = (float) result;

    printf("numerator: %lf, divisor: %lf, result: %lf, resultf: %f\n",
        numerator, divisor, result, resultf);

    return resultf;
}
```

The `printf` prints the results I expect to see:

> a x b = 1383, a = 1776, b = 4959
>   numerator: 1383.000000, divisor: 2967.690011, result: 0.466019, resultf: 0.466019

However, when I try to print the result of `calc_nnc` in another function:

```
float nnc_likeness;
unsigned int x, y;

for (y = 0; y <= y_max; y++) {
    for (x = 0; x <= x_max; x++) {
        set_image_window(&window_big, big, x, y, width, height);
        nnc_likeness = calc_nnc(&window_small, &window_big);
        printf("likeness: %f\n", nnc_likeness);
    }
}
```

I get garbage:

> likeness: 1055824384.000000

That is, I see the correct values `calc_nnc` is computing, but right after that I see a corrupted value for `nnc_likeness`.

Any idea what's happening? Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure you have the correct prototype for `calc_nnc` in the context where you call it?  It could be that your compiler is assuming a return type of `int` and that is freaking out the system.  Do you have all your warnings enabled?

Comment: In fact it looks exactly like that's what's happening - writing an answer now.

Comment: The prototype in the header is the same. I put `-Wall` and it got some interesting insight.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You probably have no prototype for `calc_nnc` in the context where you call it, so your compiler thinks its return type is `int` (as per the spec).  A quick test program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

union u {
  float f;
  int   i;
};

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  union u a;
  union u b;

  a.f = 0.466019;
  b.i = 1055824384;

  printf("%d %f\n", a.i, a.f);
  printf("%d %f\n", b.i, b.f);

  return 0;
}
```

Gives this output:

```
1055824395 0.466019
1055824384 0.466019
```

Include a correct prototype that tells your code that `calc_nnc` returns `float` and you'll be all set.  Turning more warnings on will catch this problem, too.

Comment: Yes, thanks Carl! It was exactly that. I had forgotten to include the header file. I'm rather new to C and this one got me. Thanks for your very nice explanation.